# Probability poser

Tags: probability, statistics

We play a variation of 6 card brag but have a debate over the accurate ranking of the hands.

6 cards are dealt to each player.
2 hands of 3 cards must be made.

Bearing in mind that each 3 card hand is derived from 6 cards, what is the correct ranking of hands using the traditional ideas of straight flush, straight, flush, three-of-a-kind, pair and high card?

Thank you for your help.